# HasManyThroug relations is returning SQL error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I am working on an internal PMS, where I have four models: `User`, `Company`, `Client` and `Project`.

One `Company` will have multiple `Users`, and through the `Company`, the `User` will have access to many `Clients` and `Projects`. Nothing fancy here, just a classic PMS with company, clients, users and projects.

The `User` model has a `company_id` field (one user can only be related to one company at the moment). The `Client` model also has a `company_id` field. With this I thought I could have a `HasManyThrough` relationship for `User` and `Client`, and I tried this:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough( Client::class, Company::class );
}
```

However, this returns the

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: companies.user_id (SQL:
>
> ```
> select "clients".*, "companies"."user_id" as "laravel_through_key" 
> from "clients" 
> inner join "companies" 
>     on "companies"."id" = "clients"."company_id" 
> where "companies"."user_id" = 1 
>   and "clients"."deleted_at" is null
> ```

In my database, `companies.user_id` doesn't exist, because this relation is defined by `users.company.id`. Would it be better to write a raw SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or may just use two relations like:

```
// User Model
[.....]
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Company::class, [YOUR_FK_HERE] );
}

public function clients()
{
    return $this->company->clients();
}
[....]
```

and in the Company Model

```
// Company Model
[....]
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Client::class, [YOUR_FK_HERE] );
}
[....]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This way of doing it returns `App\User::clients must return a relationship instance.` Trying to Google for this error message now, so hopefully I will find an answer. **Update:** Seems like using `$this->company->clients()` returns the relation, and not a collection. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the final solution as well!